# cant download the Windows installer - it downloads the iso instead

Tags: installation

When trying to download the Windows installer for Ubuntu, it has me download the .iso instead.

How can get the installer? I have used it before, but this time its downloading the wrong file.

Comment: Are you downloading from: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this link : 
http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/  or
http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/

Go to below,
Windows installer is "wubi" version...

Answer (score 0):

Mount the downloaded ISO on any virtual drive.

"Explore" it.

Copy the file Wubi.exe to your desktop.

Run it there keeping the iso mounted. You will find your old favrt "Install inside windows" option.

The wubi.exe present in the Iso is itself the windows installer, it just doesn't behave like that when you execute it from the CD. Take it out of the cd and run it, you will find what you are looking for :) Otherwise you can also download the Wubi separately from the Ubuntu site, named as windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of followings

http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/wubi.exe

http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/wubi.exe

12.04 is better although it is not latest. It is more stable version